# Chronicle Queue cq4 file size is not right

Tags: queue, chronicle

I have a application use chronicle queue to store data. I use hourly cycle to roll files. the lasted file size is 1.3GB. when roll file, old file size become real size,the new file size is 1.3GB.

But I find when I restart application, the chronicle queue will create a new cq4 file, this size is 1.3GB,the older file size not become real size, still is 1.3GB.

How to achieve set the older cq4 file size is real size ,not 1.3GB when the application restart.
I try to close queue when the application shutdown, but it not work.

[this is file status in my linux server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pp4Gu.png)

Comment: What version of Chronicle Queue are you using?

Comment: Chronicle Queue version is 5.20.40

Comment: Note: On Linux, Queue uses space files so this action doesn't change the amount of disk space used, but the apparent size.

Answer (score 1):

The file shrinking happens at the background upon roll. On restart you need to wait for a while before the old file will be shrunk (unless you hit some weird bug which I doubt).

Comment: When I restart application，the queue create a new cq4 files，its size is 1.3GB，the last file before restart is still 1.3GB。when I wait for some hours，the file is not shrink。So I feel so weird。

Comment: At the moment，I use du -sh commond。 it show the file that size is 1.3GB when use ll commond， is 216KB。what happened？ Why is the file size so different？

Comment: @matrixchu try du --apparent-size

Comment: yes, I use du , this command show the apparent size of cq4 file is 216KB , not 1.3GB. But Why?

Comment: You'd need to google how the file system calculates the usage and how `du` works - I suggest man du for a starter.